# Using ceph-deploy when APT repos are down

Tags: ceph

Using `ceph-deploy install ...` fails when the download.ceph.com website/repo is down. Is there a way to install from a mirror? In the docs you can see `--repo-url` option, but it seems to still download from download.ceph.com. See hereafter:

```
ceph-deploy install --repo-url http://eu.ceph.com/debian-jewel/  ogw01
[ceph_deploy.conf][DEBUG ] found configuration file at: /home/bstor/.cephdeploy.conf
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ] Invoked (1.5.35): /usr/bin/ceph-deploy install --repo-url http://eu.ceph.com/debian-jewel/ ogw01
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ] ceph-deploy options:
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  verbose                       : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  testing                       : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  cd_conf                       : <ceph_deploy.conf.cephdeploy.Conf instance at 0x7faec06d8638>
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  cluster                       : ceph
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  dev_commit                    : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  install_mds                   : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  stable                        : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  default_release               : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  username                      : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  adjust_repos                  : True
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  func                          : <function install at 0x7faec0b1b230>
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  install_all                   : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  repo                          : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  host                          : ['ogw01']
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  install_rgw                   : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  install_tests                 : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  repo_url                      : http://eu.ceph.com/debian-jewel/
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  ceph_conf                     : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  install_osd                   : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  version_kind                  : stable
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  install_common                : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  overwrite_conf                : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  quiet                         : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  dev                           : master
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  nogpgcheck                    : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  local_mirror                  : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  release                       : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  install_mon                   : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  gpg_url                       : None
[ceph_deploy.install][DEBUG ] Installing stable version jewel on cluster ceph hosts ogw01
[ceph_deploy.install][DEBUG ] Detecting platform for host ogw01 ...
[ogw01][DEBUG ] connection detected need for sudo
[ogw01][DEBUG ] connected to host: ogw01
[ogw01][DEBUG ] detect platform information from remote host
[ogw01][DEBUG ] detect machine type
[ceph_deploy.install][INFO  ] Distro info: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
[ogw01][INFO  ] installing Ceph on ogw01
[ceph_deploy.install][WARNIN] --gpg-url was not used, will fallback
[ceph_deploy.install][WARNIN] using GPG fallback: https://download.ceph.com/keys/release.asc
[ogw01][INFO  ] using custom repository location: http://eu.ceph.com/debian-jewel/
[ogw01][INFO  ] Running command: sudo wget -O release.asc https://download.ceph.com/keys/release.asc
[ogw01][WARNIN] --2016-10-11 14:06:38--  https://download.ceph.com/keys/release.asc
[ogw01][WARNIN] Resolving download.ceph.com (download.ceph.com)... 173.236.253.173, 2607:f298:6050:51f3:f816:3eff:fe71:9135
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lines:

```
[ceph_deploy.install][WARNIN] --gpg-url was not used, will fallback
[ceph_deploy.install][WARNIN] using GPG fallback: https://download.ceph.com/keys/release.asc
```

indicate that download.ceph.com is only used for the **gpg** part. You can also give `--gpg-url` option. The following command should work, as it also uses the mirror's key for deploying:

```
ceph-deploy install --repo-url http://eu.ceph.com --gpg-url http://eu.ceph.com/keys/release.asc   ogw01
```

Comment: I tried to use a mirror on when apparently *.ceph.com was not resolvable, so, since every mirror is a subdomain of ceph.com using a mirror didn't help in this case.